# how to add toastr.js in my angular 4 component

Tags: javascript, angular, components, toastr

I am trying to add toastr.js in my angular component

by toasts.js placed in `../../../../../scripts/thirdparty/toastr.js`

but when i am trying to import it just line this

```
import * as toastr from 'toastr';
```

after installing npm install "@type/toastr" still it is not including.

Answer (score 2):

there is an `ngx-toastr` package you can use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr

run `npm install --save ngx-toastr`

Then add the toastr.css in your `.angular-cli.json` file in the styles section like

`"styles": [
        "../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
        "styles.scss"
      ]`

Import the `ToastrModule` in your module, where you want to use it like this:

`ToastrModule.forRoot({
      positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right',
      progressBar: true
    })`

After this setup you can import the `ToastrService` in your component

`import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';`

inject it in the constructor

`constructor(private toastrService: ToastrService){}`

and use it

`this.toastrService.error(message);`